# String with Backslash and Quotes in Python is problems galore

Tags: python, quotes, backslash

I've a normal string, that I like to send to a program, which only eats my string as `"\"text\""`, exactly like that. But in Python I can `print` it like that but I can't assign it like that. See the following:

My text:

```
In [12]:

i = fieldList[0]
print str(i.name)
Y03M01D01
```

Which I can `print` as `"\"text\""`

```
In [13]:

field_new = '"\\"'+str(i.name)+'\\""'
print field_new
"\"Y03M01D01\""
```

But this is how it is eaten by the program

```
In [14]:

field_new
Out[14]:
'"\\"Y03M01D01\\""'
```

Which is not equal to `"\"text\""` and so my code fails. 
Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: How do you pass the string to the program?

Comment: What's the goal here?  Do you want the string to have slashes in it, or are you just using them to escape the double quotes?

Comment: i think `repr` and `str` are the issues and yet you are not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @mgilson I would like to have the string to have 2 slashes in it. @Tzach If I do `"\"Y03M01D01\""` then it works and when I send `field_new` it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `r` prefix for the string in your comparison will have python treat the string as raw (all backslashes are unescaped).

```
>>> i = "text"
>>> field_new = '"\\"'+str(i)+'\\""'
>>> field_new
'"\\"text\\""'
>>> field_new == r'"\"text\""'
True
```

Comment: If I do this in IPython I get the following: `In [4]: field_new = '"\\"'+str(i)+'\\""'
In [5]: field_new
Out[5]: '"\\"<geoprocessing describe field object object at 0x0CCE8C38>\\""'`